# Manipulatings with istream

Tags: c++

I want to make something like history of commands for my console-application. It does only one thing: check for input in infinite cycle (with std::getline(std::cin, ...)). As example, you can look at **gdb** (console debugger). After running it we can input commands and switch them with keyboard arrows.

The question is how can I "hook" arrows pressing during waiting for input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want this for a private project or a project that will be released under a GNU license you may want to look at [the GNU readline library](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html).

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [GNU readline](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) which

> provides line-editing and history capabilities for interactive programs.